# iPhone HTTP streaming server components

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, stream

Hi
I am setting up HTTP live streaming for iOS. It is a RTSP stream that I will get on UDP and pass it on to the MediaStreamSegmenter. My questions are:

-Do I need a Mac based server so that mediastreamsegmenter tool can actually do it job? If yes then do I have any alternatives?

-Can pass a remote machine address to mediastreamsegmenter to store the segmented files and Index file?

I cant really afford a server and a Mac server for that matter....

Replies appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cheap and easy way of doing it using VLC player. I had to compile VLC for this but you can look for latest nightly builds to get the LIVEHTTP plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Mac server. In fact, if you use Amazon S3, you can combine that with cloudfront to do RTMP streaming of your files from S3 to the user. check it out: http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/#highlights

You can simply pass the stream address to the media stream segmenter, and you're good to go.